# Custom Keyboard Crash With Custom Sound

Tags: ios, ios8, keyboard

I'm working on a custom keyboard in swift and am facing some issues with the custom keyboard sound effect.  I have my own .caf file and am trying to run it, but every time I try it the keyboard crashes from the first button i press.

When I try to play the original key sound from Apple, it works fine. But not with my custom sound. Any ideas???

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        let path  = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Keyboard Key Sound 1 copy", ofType: "caf")!
        let pathURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        var audioEffect : SystemSoundID = 0
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID( pathURL as! CFURLRef  , &audioEffect)

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(audioEffect)

        })
```